# How to split x-axis of matplotlib scatter graph manually when x is ranging 0, 0.001, 0.01, ..., 1000?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a scatter graph with mathplotlib to indicate accuracy change (y-axis) for different 'C' values (x-axis) on the Linear SVM algorithm. The problem is:

```
C_values = [0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000]
```

Because of the values "0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1", this area is shown terribly narrow and overlapped on the graph as you can see on the image.

This is my code:

```
plt.figure()
plt.xlabel('C values')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.scatter(C_values, svc_acc_scores)
plt.xticks([0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000])
```

This is the result I get:

[image: result]

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is a standard `matplotlib` question, and has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: try using a logarithmic x-axis

Comment: @baccandr Thank you for the advice but it did not work for me.

Comment: Unfortunately this question does not allow to see why a logarithmic axes would solve your problem. So it would probably stay unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a logarithmic scale and having an x-value of 0 is problematic, as `log(0) = -∞`.
Therefore, best to leave out the zero. Some sample code:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

C_values = [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000]
svc_acc_scores = [0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8]

plt.figure()
plt.xlabel('C values')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.scatter(C_values, svc_acc_scores)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.xticks([0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000])
plt.show()
```

[image: sample plot]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I never thought that the problem is based on having an x-value of 0.